# Scale numeric matrix into values from 0 - 1 uniformly, in R

Tags: r

I am running into a scaling problem with several matrices I am working with. Here is an example of my matrix:

```
my_matrix = matrix(data = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,25), nrow = 3)
```

My current method of scaling between 0 to 1 is using the equation (value - min) / (max - min). Using this on the entire matrix gives the following:

```
mn = min(my_matrix); mx = max(my_matrix);
(my_matrix - mn) / (mx - mn)

           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.00000000 0.1250000 0.2500000
[2,] 0.04166667 0.1666667 0.2916667
[3,] 0.08333333 0.2083333 1.0000000
```

I understand the calculation, as well as why I am receiving this matrix. However, I would much prefer to scale 0 to 1 based on percentiles, and receive this matrix instead:

```
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.11111111 0.4444444 0.7777778
[2,] 0.22222222 0.5555556 0.8888889
[3,] 0.33333333 0.6666667 1.0000000
```

Does anybody know an easy way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: `my_matrix[] <- rank(my_matrix) / length(my_matrix)` ?

Comment: didn't know of rank. this is great. i'l use this although it looks like i will need to re-construct back into a matrix

Comment: Equivalent: `my_matrix[] <- dplyr::cume_dist(my_matrix)`